# Spark sql using programmatic schema will throw strange exception

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, schema

(Problem already solved!)

I'm trying to use "Programmatically Specifying the Schema"(http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html).
I have this my.txt file as input:

```
"A", 1, 2
"B", 2, 3
"B", 13,6
"C", 3, 4
```

Then I have a spark program to read and interpret it:

```
val rowRdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("my.txt")
.map(_.split(","))
.map(a => Row(a(0), a(1).trim.toInt, a(2).trim.toInt))
val schema = StructType("a b c".split(" ")
.map(f => StructField(f, StringType, nullable = true)))
spark.createDataFrame(rowRdd, schema).createOrReplaceTempView("people")
spark.sql("select * from people").show()
```

When running with spark-submit, it gives exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Integer is not a valid external type for schema of string
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, a), StringType), true) AS a#0
+- if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString, validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object), 0, a), StringType), true)
   :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object).isNullAt
   :  :- assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true], top level row object)
   :  :  +- input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]
   :  +- 0
... ...(many lines)
```

In fact, in my 3rd line I had

```
Row(a(0), a(1).trim.toInt, a(2).trim.toInt))
```

The first element is string, I didn't cast it into integer. But the error message is "java.lang.Integer is not a valid external type for schema of string".

So where did I get wrong in my program and how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

---

Problem solve, should not contain "" to refer to fields, change input file as to be:

```
A, 1, 2
B, 2, 3
B, 13,6
C, 3, 4
```

Then everything works fine!

Comment: Either remove the toInt calls in line 3 or change your schema to contain (StringType, IntegerType, IntegerType) rather than all StringType

Comment: Thanks!.............